# How to I configure Visual Studio 2013 to Link to Windows Kit 10 and not 8.1

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2013, environment-variables

I have spent the last 2 hours Googleing around this subject and not being able to get this to work so hoping some Visual Studio Guru will be able to help me out.

First some basics.
I am developing on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2013 Professional(32 bit) and my VS is linking perfectly fine to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1`

I also have the 8.0 version of Windows Kit installed but from  what I can tell this isn't being used by VS2013. Similarly I have Visual Studio 2010 installed but not being used for this project.

My code requires use of the `IsWindows10OrGreater()` function from VersionHelpers.h which is only available in Windows kit 10.

I have installed Windows Kit 10 and this has installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`

So far so good. The installation of Windows Kit 10 created an environment variable. It did not remove the old Windows Kit 8.1 Environment variable but I have since tried that to resolve the problem without success.

The problem is visual studio 2013 is linking to the 8.1 sdk.

I have tried adding the 10 path to the INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH(its already in PATH) as I saw these where getting set in `vcvars32.bat`. This didn't work.

After quite a bit of digging I managed to find under `project>properties>C/C++/Preprocessor>Preprocessor` Definitions and in the Macros I noticed that there are a some Marcos defined that point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1` but I can find no way of altering these macros.

Can anybody tell me how I can configure Visual Studio to point to the correct SDK.

Thanks in advance

Tomas

Comment: Are you having issues including *VersionHelpers.h*, or does it fail when linking against *kernel32.dll*?

Comment: It includes fine using < > not an absolute path but if I open the included file its the one in Windows Kits/8.1/ and I can use functions from that file find for example iswindows8orgreater()

Comment: So it **doesn't** include the correct file.

Comment: No not the correct version

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my old SDK 8 for VS2010, I made up this property sheet which appears to work.
You'll want to verify the folders are correct for your WDK 10 installation and note that this is for x64 only.

Create file Windows10SDK_X64.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExecutablePath>$(VCInstallDir)bin\x86_amd64;$(VCInstallDir)bin;$(WindowsSdkDir)bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\Tools\bin;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\tools;$(VSInstallDir)Common7\ide;$(ProgramFiles)\HTML Help Workshop;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\bin;$(MSBuildToolsPath32);$(VSInstallDir);$(SystemRoot)\SysWow64;$(FxCopDir);$(PATH)</ExecutablePath>
    <IncludePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\um;$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\shared;$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;</IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath>$(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64;$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib\x64</LibraryPath>
    <ExcludePath>$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\um;$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\shared;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;$(MSBuildToolsPath32);$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(VCInstallDir)lib;</ExcludePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
<ItemDefinitionGroup />
</Project>
```

Make sure to clean and rebuild.